# Во время написания мини-игры в JS возникла проблема перепрыгивания персонажа через препятствие

Tags: javascript, css-animation

когда left-положение препятствия становится равно ширине персонажа срабатывает alert(Game over). Не понимаю где ошибка в коде, по идее препятствие должно проходить дальше при перепрыгивании персонажем

```js
const dog = document.getElementById('dog');
const fire = document.getElementById('fire');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    jump();
});
function jump() {
  if (dog.classList !='jump') {
    dog.classList.add('jump');
  } setTimeout( function() {
    dog.classList.remove('jump')
  }, 300)
}
let isAlive = setInterval (function() {
    let dogTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(dog).getPropertyValue('top'));
    let dogLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(dog).getPropertyValue('width'));
    let fireLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(fire).getPropertyValue('left'));
    if (fireLeft<100 && fireLeft>0 && dogTop>=390) {
        alert('GAME OVER')
    }
}, 10)
```

```css
.game {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin: auto;
}
#dog {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(img/dogg.jpg);
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 400px;
}
#fire {
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url(img/fire.png);
    background-size: 50px 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 310px;
    left: 850px;
    animation: fireMove 3s infinite linear;
   } 
@keyframes fireMove {
     0% {
      left: 850px;
     }
     100% {
        left: -50px;
     }   
    }

.jump {
    animation: jump 0.5s linear;   
}
@keyframes jump {
    0% {
     top: 400px;
    }
    30% {
      top: 300px;
    }
   
    50% {
     top: 300px;
    }

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game">
        <div id="dog"></div>
        <div id="fire"></div>
    </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

```
    }
    80% {
     top: 300px;
    }
    100% {
       top: 400px;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Даже не знаю с чего начать

1. Убери background-image и поставь вместо dog и fire какой нибудь цвет, и ты увидишь, что коллизия всё же возникает (они дотрагиваются друг к другу).
2. Это абсолютно неправильный подход, получать данные о коллизии и позиции элементов игры из CSS, это все должно делаться с помощью JS.
3. Вот как правильно проверять коллизию: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MyPLZSGS3s&t=113s&ab_channel=ChrisCourses